Find all Pageable entities with only specific attributes selected
As the title described, I'm having trouble in selecting only the data I want from a database given my entity classes:
@Entity(name = "Movie")
@Table(name = "movie")
public class Movie implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 300)
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 300)
    private String title;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 1000)
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false, length = 1000)
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Genre.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "movie_genres",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false))
    private List<Genre> genres = new ArrayList<>();

    //Constructors, getters and setters excluded for brevity

}

@Entity(name = "Genre")
@Table(name = "genre")
public class Genre implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 300)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 300)
    private String name;

    //Constructors, getters and setters excluded for brevity

}

Is there a way to write a Spring Data JPA repository method that returns all paged movies, with only id and title selected (without description), and genres eagerly loaded in this case alone? Something akin to this method:
List<Movie> findAll(Pageable pageable);

Note that i wish for it to return a List, and not Page, as Page makes another count request to the database, which I don't need. I am using Spring Boot version 3.3, with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and spring-boot-starter-web as dependencies. My database is MySQL.
I tried everything, from reading the Spring Data JPA User Guide, to trying different combinations with @Query and @EntityGraph, only for it to not compile at all, or to favour only one of them, selecting all eager data including description.
For instance the following does not compile as it does not recognize the constructor, even though I have such constructor in Movie entity:
@Query("SELECT new Movie(m.id,m.title,m.genres) FROM Movie m")
List<Movie> findAllPageable(Pageable pageable);


JQL supports selecting specific properties of your entities in isolation, but if you want the entities themselves then you get all the properties of each one.

Consider defining a separate DTO class with a relevant constructor

@JohnBollinger There has to be a cleaner solution instead of writing a complex JQL. I provided a simple example with Movie and Genre. Now assume movie has critiques and each critique has comments and each of critiques and comments have likes/dislikes, and assume they are lazy loaded. There has to be a solution that gives me full control over what gets selected for eagerly. EntityGraph looked like such a solution, but i couldn't make it work.

@NSarj I already have a DTO class unto which i am transforming my DB class, that's not the issue. The issue is in having complete control over what attributes get selected from database in paginated form, so that it returns a List instead of Page. I can chose what information client sees with DTO class, but i don't want unnecessary data being selected from database in the first place, as that can lead to performance issues.

I mean that you are trying to select a Movie into a Movie: new Movie(m.id,m.title,m.genres) FROM Movie m

@JuiceWizard, I'm not sure where you get complicated from my previous comment.  You're already writing JQL, and a query to select a subset of object properties would be simpler than the query at the end of the question.  But I think you're missing the underlying point: you seem to be fighting against your ORM.  If you dislike or cannot afford working, for the most part, in terms of whole entities, then an ORM approach to persistence such as JPA / Spring-data is probably not for you.
